# WPF .NET 6.0 Error Loading image when logged in a non-admin user

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, .net-6.0

I have a strange issue I have an image brush as background bounded to a imageurl property and some images only loads when user is logged in as administrator otherwise I get the following error

Xaml:

```
<Border.Background>
         <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding ImageUrl}"/>
</Border.Background>
```

Error:

```
System.NotSupportedException: No imaging component suitable to complete this operation was found.
 ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x88982F8B): The component initialization has failed. (0x88982F8B)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.SetupDecoderFromUriOrStream(Uri uri, Stream stream, BitmapCacheOption cacheOption, Guid& clsId, Boolean& isOriginalWritable, Stream& uriStream, UnmanagedMemoryStream& unmanagedMemoryStream, SafeFileHandle& safeFilehandle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateFromUriOrStream(Uri baseUri, Uri uri, Stream stream, BitmapCreateOptions createOptions, BitmapCacheOption cacheOption, RequestCachePolicy uriCachePolicy, Boolean insertInDecoderCache)
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.LateBoundBitmapDecoder.EnsureDecoder()
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.LateBoundBitmapDecoder.DownloadCallback(Object arg)
```

dotnet on pc:

```
Host:
  Version:      6.0.11
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       943474ca16

.NET SDKs installed:
  No SDKs were found.

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

what I tried:

- turn off firewall
- no web filter
- give local user full access to folder where the app is installed
- Entering URL in browser and it loaded successfully

Comment: Could you please give an example urls which cause a problem?

Comment: I don’t know how long this link will be available https://v5.airtableusercontent.com/v1/10/10/1668398400000/xcwJoaNOrLdvvtU1at3z1g/9EAVxqBs3BTz-yjk7mTgCNh4NOEQKPM7XH1wl74vFuv9EfTFw7LGXD5AE8EvBHatmvFFfz90EsIllpFqD7TUdgjtpoyPBuQ_zME8Eg_Q9K4/nHBAwe2Zo0ZxmAj_U4gNhjQ9AiTEw4ez3VH4xbv3mBw